# How to Alter table column dynamically using PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, html, sql

I added a form including an input field and a button. Now I am trying to pass the text from the input field into my query as the column name when the button is pressed. the form's method is post and the action is the path to the PHP file that holds the function. The text from the input field is held in the variable `$subject` and now I'm trying to pass this variable into to the query. I'm running my application on XAMPP server and it keeps on giving me this

**error:**"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''English' VARCHAR(100)' at line 1".

How do I do this successfully?

**WEB PAGE SOURCE:**

```
<form action="addons/functions.php" method="POST">
                            <br><h1 class="bg-warning">Subject</h1>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="add Subject" name="subject" class="input-group"><br>
                            <button type="submit" name="addsub" class="btn-success btn-dark">Add Subject</button>
                            <span class="mailspan"><?php 

                            if(isset($_SESSION['message'])){
                                echo $_SESSION['message'];
                                unset ($_SESSION['message']);
                            }

                    ?></span>
                        </form>
```

**PHP FILE SOURCE:**

```
if (isset($_POST['addsub'])){
    $sub=$_POST['subject'];
    $conn->query("ALTER TABLE students ADD '$sub' VARCHAR(100)" ) or die($conn->error);
    $_SESSION['message']='Subject added successfully!';
 header("location:../admin.php");
}
```

Comment: why would you have the need to alter the table for that, seems like the problem is deeper like its not normalised

Comment: I pasted an incorrect source earlier. See if the the PHP FILE SOURCE makes sense now.

Comment: Don't do it like this. Create a second table `subject`, and a third acting as a pivot tables to connect students to subject. That's how relational databases work.

Comment: Are you adding columns to the table dynamically to store values? If thats the case I can suggest a few sources to better your understanding of relational databases. This code is also susceptible to SQL injection. You may want to look into prepared statements.

Comment: Please take a look at an older question of mine in regards to altering live tables https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/402066/altering-database-tables-on-the-fly-why-is-this-a-bad-idea

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a missing word "COLUMN" in this query if you are going to add new column.
Instead of this

```
"ALTER TABLE students ADD '$sub' VARCHAR(100)"
```

Try

```
"ALTER TABLE students ADD COLUMN '$sub' VARCHAR(100)"
```

But like other guys said, read about prepared statements to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: Depending on OPs needs this a may be an improper approach. Other than researching SQL injection OP may want to research proper database design. Making alterations to live tables is far from preferable.